# Jhipster blank page

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jhipster

[image]I started working on web services. Whenever I try to run existing project in Netbeans. Project builds successfully with result

```
Application 'Project Name' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8090
    External:   http://192.168.1.4:8090
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
```

When ever I go to browser and try to run this URL. I don't get response. I have no idea what's wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Is this a SOAP or REST service? WHat are you expecting to see?

Comment: I want to see Swagger API for testing.

Comment: Actually this project is configured on other machine using JHipster. I want run this project on my MAC. I got project and opened in Netbeans. It builds successfully. But when I try to access it via browser. It gives me blank page with url returned. I'm expecting a JHipster project in response.

Comment: I added an image what I'm expecting. Please help me.

Comment: Your setup is not clear, please edit your question and say on which machines the gateway, registry and services are running. It could be an issue of not using right IP addresses in bootstrap*.yml. Try also running the apps from shell using mvnw or gradlew as it could be a bad configuration fo netbeans project.

Comment: Hi  Gaël Marziou! I am running services on local host. This project is under development. The project is configured properly on another MAC. I want to run same project under my MAC. Whenever I use command ./mvnw, it builds successfully as i mentioned. When i try to access IP on browser, it shows blank page. I think it is able to make connection. It is not showing This site can’t be reached or localhost refused to connect. It is not able to display jhipster project.

Comment: So have you run yarn, yarn start or yarn webpack:build? See http://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular

Answer (score 0):

These commands helped me

1) yarn
2) yarn webpack:build
3) ./mvnw